# compactness in the space of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am always getting confused by the idea of compactness so I would like some help to see whether a set is compact. (I need this to prove existence of a solution of a map)

So let $D\in\mathbb{C}$ be open and bounded and let $C^\omega(D)$ be the space of functions analytic on $D$ equipped with the supremum norm. Let also $F\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{R}_+)$, with $\sup_{z\in D} F(|z|)=M>0$.

Now I define $A=\{f\in C^\omega(D):|f(z)|\le F(|z|) \}$. Is this set compact in $C^\omega(D)$?

I know that for it to be compact I need to prove that any open set in $A$ admits a finite cover. Yet I cannot see how to prove this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "supremum norm" is NOT a norm on your space because analytic functions needn't be bounded. If you consider instead the space of bounded analytic functions you get a Banach space and for the constant function $F(x)=1$ your set is the unit ball which is not compact (because this is so in *every* infinite dimensional Banach space).

On the other hand, the space of all analytic functions is usually endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on all compact sets (instead of a single norm you have a sequence of norms $\|f\|_n=\sup\lbrace |f(z)|: z\in K_n\rbrace$ where $K_n$ form a compact exhaustion). By a theorem of Montel, all bounded subsets are relatively compact (therefore, such topological vector spaces are called Montel spaces). The main ingredient in the proof of Montel's theorem is the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

By definition of your set $A$ it is quite easy to see that $A$ is bounded, that is $\sup\lbrace \|f\|_n: f\in A\rbrace <\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

---

Edit. A nice exposition of the functional analytic view to complex analysis is the book of Luecking and Rubel (Springer 1984). If you fix $D$ compact the space of functions analytic in a neighborhood is a so-called LB-space (inductive limit of Banach spaces) and it is also Montel (see also the book of Luecking and Rubel or the *Introduction to Functional Analysis* by Meise and Vogt).

Comment: +1. Note that $A$ is also closed, so that it is compact indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is really helpful. I have a couple of questions though. If i choose $D$ is compact and get functions analytic on an open set containing $D$ with finite supremum, will this space work? Do I need a family of $K_n$'s, or I can get the same with just one compact set? And finally, where should I read about these Montel spaces? Do you have any text to suggest?